# Proof of metric space completion in Fred H Croom's Principles in Topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

I have problem with understanding the proof of Theorem 3.19 about metric space completion. The proof starts on page 91, my problem starts on page 92. The proof that I have problem with, goes as following:

*The completeness of $(Y, d')$ can be proved as follows. The details are left as an exercise. First note that each Cauchy sequence in the dense subspace $e(X)$ of $Y$ converges. To see this, let $\{[<z^k>]\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $e(X)$, where each sequence $<z^k>$ has constant value $z^k$, a point in $X$, $k = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$. Then $\{z^k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$ and determines a member of $Y$ to which the given Cauchy sequence in $e(X)$ converges.*

*Now let $\{[<x_n^k>]\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Since $e(X)$ is dense in $Y$, there is for each positive integer $k$ a member $[<z^k>]$ in $e(X)$ whose distance from $[<x_n^k>]$ is less than $1/k$. It follows that $\{[<z^k>]\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence which, as just demonstrated, converges to some member of $Y$.*

*By the way the members $[<z^k>]$ were chosen, it follows that $\{[<x_n^k>]\}_{k=1}^\infty$ converges to the same member of $Y$. Thus $Y$ is complete.*

I couldn't understand why he chooses Cauchy sequence with $k$ power $<z^k>$, instead of simply using $<z>$, and in the same way, why $<x_n^k>$ instead of simply using $<x_n>$? Or may be I understood incorrectly the meaning of $z^k$ and $x_n^k$?

Comment: I think k is not a power. In an arbitrary metric space I don’t even know what a power is. It should mean just a normal index

Comment: Yes, it seems that instead of having double indices the author prefers to have an index and an exponent.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you all! Now reading it again just boiling my blood haha

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you all! Now reading it again just boiling my blood haha

Comment: In mathematical writing, using a subscript--superscript index pair $a^j_i$ is a fairly common variation on using a double subscript pair $a_{ij}$. In this situation one should not think of $j$ as an "exponent".

Answer (score 1):

The comments already answered the question, so I just want to rewrite the proof with a simpler notation that could emphasizes more on the basic idea of the proof. I hope this could help to understand the proof faster.

The basic idea is to create a new metric space **ONLY** from classes of equivalence Cauchy sequences from the original metric space. By having members only from classes of equivalence Cauchy sequences, it guarantees all of its Cauchy sequences converge because... well, they are already Cauchy sequences in the original metric space. The rest of the proof is a technicality to ensure the proof is rigorous.

So the first step is to create metric space $Y$ consisting classes of equivalence Cauchy sequences from $X$. Let's denote every element of this metric space $Y$ with $A$.

The second step is to create a map of every element of $X$ to a class of equivalence Cauchy sequences in $Y$. Denote this map with $e(X)$.

Now to prove that $e(X)$ is a dense subspace of $Y$, we can do this:

Because every $A$ is a class of equivalence Cauchy sequences in $X$, means every $A$ has at least one Cauchy sequence $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ in $X$. As $A$ could be represented by $a_n$, we could always pick an element very close to $a_n$, for example $a_{n-1}$, that has its $e(a_{n-1})$ in $Y$ very close to $A$.

To prove that $Y$ is complete, we could do this:

Denote a Cauchy sequence in $e(X)$ with $<A_n> = \{A_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ (*and yes, this $<A_n>$ is a Cauchy sequence of classes of equivalence Cauchy sequences in $X$*). Each element of $<A_n>$ which is: $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n$ has at least one Cauchy sequence in $X$ as following: $a_{1_1}, a_{1_2}, \cdots, a_{1_n}$ for $A_1$; $a_{2_1}, a_{2_2}, \cdots, a_{2_n}$ for $A_2$; $\cdots$; and $a_{n_1}, a_{n_2}, \cdots, a_{n_n}$ for $A_n$. Each element of $<A_n>$ could be represented by $a_{1_n}, a_{2_n}, \cdots, a_{n_n}$, which is just a Cauchy sequence in $X$ and determines a member of $Y$ where it converges. (*Why in $Y$? Because $e(X)$ is dense in $Y$.*)

Let $<B_n> = \{B_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Because $e(X)$ is dense in $Y$, we could choose $A_n$ very close to $B_n$, but as has been showed above that $<A_n>$ converges  to some member of $Y$, it follows that $<B_n>$ also converges to the same member of $Y$.